# Atomic increment of double data type in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, nosql

Is there any way to atomically increment a double data type without implementing distributed lock on the primary key?
Maybe in a similar way a counter works:

```
UPDATE user SET usage = usage + 3.45 WHERE user_id = 3400435592
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing in Cassandra, but if you have fixed precision then you could use plain counters by scaling your data appropriately, eg:

```
UPDATE user SET usage = usage + 345 WHERE user_id = 3400435592
```

where you implicitly use "cents" as your base, or

```
UPDATE user SET usage = usage + 3450 WHERE user_id = 3400435592
```

where you use "millis" as your base.

However, keep in mind that your increment problem is far more general than a "double" increment. If you can tolerate under/over increment then go on and use Cassandra counters. If you're modeling money transactions then the only reliable increment thing I can think of is a queue message processing thing, done at application level, and that doesn't use doubles!